# What causes setTimeout to crash a browser, and how can it safely be used?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading

I'm building a game in HTML5 that relies on setTimeout events to generate a large tile-based map gradually while the user plays (instead of forcing the user to wait 1+ minute for world gen to finish). The game calls setTimeout thousands (or even tens of thousands) of times in very close proximity, with random intervals. Once each thread has finished it calls setTimeout recursively until a base case is met.

Despite this, and despite the game being rather graphically intensive (with WebGL), it runs quite well, even on mobile devices. However, after anywhere from a few seconds to a few minutes, the browser will sometimes crash.

[image: The actual page crashes (not a JavaScript bug per se).]

I have a couple of theories as to why this is happening, but if I'm to continue using this technique I'd like to be sure I understand the issue better.

- Is it because I have too many threads going at once? Strangely this issue sometimes takes as much as 10 minutes to hit (if I disable the base case) - so during that time it runs fine with all the threads but then suddenly explodes (though they do get called at random intervals between 0 and 100 ms).
- Is it because setTimeout doesn't allow memory to be released from the stack? This seems far fetched to me but it would explain things. The program will typically not crash if the base case detection is enabled (but occasionally it does).
- Is there possibly a bug with the browser that prevents it from cleaning up properly from each call?
- Is it because the browser is glitching and scheduling two setTimeouts to run at the exact same time?
- Is it because the browser is detecting a possible infinite loop?
- Is it because js code was running when a setTimeout triggered but didn't finish in time, resulting in a delayed/expired timeout (or several of them building up)?

Finally, is there any way to use setTimeout safely, so that I do not have to worry about this issue when I deploy the game for others to play?

Comment: Javascript in the browser is not multi-threaded. Are you sure that the JS is valid (check console) and also that the interval for timeout is not too short. I.e. browser is just running around in circles

Comment: The code is perfect - I've been living in the console while I've develop this game. The actual call to setTimeout has the following interval: Math.random() * 100.

Comment: Is the number of milliseconds from 0-100 rather small? Change the 100 to 1000 and see what happens. Perhaps have the timeout of at least 100ms

Comment: @EdHeal Maybe it is short, but when I set it to 0 it exhibits roughly the same behavior (doesn't seem accelerated and the threads seem to wait for others to finish before they start).

Comment: JS is not multi-threaded. Why not set it to some larger value and see if the problem goes away. If it does then you know where the problem is.

Comment: @EdHeal Of course, by "thread" I mean execution of the generating function. The program is designed assuming only one thread will execute at a time. I've changed the delay to a constant 100 (and will do other tests) to see what happens, but I don't think this is a valid test to determine the source of the problem. Increasing the timeout might just make the issue exponentially less likely to happen without actually revealing the cause. Then it might crash on other people's computers or mobile devices when I deploy it.

Comment: @EdHeal So it doesn't crash (or perhaps a crash becomes very unlikely) if I have a fixed interval of 100ms. But I'd still like to know what is certain to be a safe interval? And why did a short interval result in a crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been bugging me. I did the following on jsfiddle:

```
function killtime(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++);
}

for(var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++){
    setTimeout(killtime(), 1);
}
```

And no crash. That's way more timeouts getting blocked than my program is producing. So this couldn't be a problem with setTimeout alone. I now believe that the problem may have been that the setTimeouts were calling a lot of blocking code which may have somehow interfered with the timing requirements of some of the WebGl libraries I am relying on - that's just a best guess though. The issue is impossible to isolate without running Chrome in a debug environment. And the problem is very difficult to reproduced in a more simpler program. I did notice that mobile browsers are much more likely to crash than desktop browsers, so I'll be sure to do a lot of my debugging there.

What I can say is that there is likely nothing wrong with the setTimeout function per se (at least not directly).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use setInterval to see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: I hadn't. I don't want the function to run on an interval. But for the sake of this answer I did this: 
var ti = Math.random() * 100;
var i = setInterval(..., ti);
setTimeout(function (i) { clearInterval(i); }, ti + 1, i); 

And it does still crash.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, maybe you could try to use HTML5 Web Workers in order to prevent your code from crashing.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=R3osfr6BxZg